# Delete Multiple Entries in CSV Cell

Tags: csv, powershell

I have the csv below

```
  Total Devices Affected      Comments 
          5                 Host1.Domain
                            Host2.Domain
                            Host3.Domain
                            Host4.Domain
                            Host5.Domain

          4                 Host1.Domain
                            Host2.Domain
                            Host3.Domain
                            Host4.Domain
```

I want to be able to delete entries Host2.Domain and Host3.Domain from each cell without deleting the whole cell. I only have Windows PowerShell to work with. Is this possible?

```
$data = Import-Csv .\acas.csv

 foreach($title in $data)

{
$totaldevices = $title."Total Devices Affected"
$comments = $title."Comments"
}
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried? Are the values in the row newline delimited?

Comment: I haven't tried anything as of yet to delete the one entry. I was thinking I could user a for each loop to read each column but I have no idea what I could do to just remove one entry with out deleting the whole cell. I edited above with what I have at the moment.They are not delimited.

Comment: Usually it is expected that you have tried something when asking question on SO. If those "Comments" cells are not delimited then how are multiple entries in one cell

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I wanted to know if it was possible and maybe get a suggestion on where to start. I thought this was a site where we help each other if we had questions.  I'm fairly new to PowerShell, I guess I don't quite understand what delimited means.

Comment: Like I said earlier it is possible but something looks wrong with the data you presented. Are all the host.domain entries only in 2 cells? or are they in 9. I can't tell the relationship from looking at you sample. Thanks for showing some code.

Comment: they are in 2 separate cells. so host1-5.domain are in one and host1-4.domain are in another cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the `Comments` field in the csv is a multi-line string, here's how I would do it with a simple `for` loop:

```
# Define the host names we want to remove
$PendingRemoval = "Host2.Domain","Host3.Domain"

# Import the original data set
$Data = Import-Csv .\original.csv

for($i = 0; $i -lt $data.Count; $i++)
{
    # Grab all hostnames from the comments field
    $Comments = $Data[$i].Comments -split "`r?`n"

    # Filter out unwanted ones
    $Comments = $Comments |Where-Object {$_ -notin $PendingRemoval}

    # Update original row
    $Data[$i].Comments = $Comments -join [System.Environment]::NewLine
}

# Export it to a new csv
$Data |Export-Csv .\updated.csv
```

Comment: Thanks! That works but what if I don't want a new document can I do an `export-csv` to update to the original csv in your case is `original.csv`

Comment: `Export-Csv .\original.csv -Force`

Comment: now I know what `$Comments = $Data[$i].Comments` is.. can you explain `-split "`r?`n"`

Comment: `-split` accepts a regular expression pattern by which to split a string into multiple strings. The first part means "maybe a carriage return" and the second part means "definitely a line feed" - this way it works on both Windows-style newlines (CR + LF) and unix-style newlines (LF)